# Deploy SSDT Tabular Model target of invocation error

Tags: azure, deployment, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I'm setting up a CI/CD pipeline for our analysis services deployments. I've configured out input files to support the wizards CLI.  When I deploy our model via the wizard UI and just click through the screens i get no deployment errors.  When I attempt to call the wizard via the CLI `wizardPath modelPath /s` I get the the error `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`  I have my ProcessOption set to DoNotProcess.  I've corrected my validation and authentication errors.  I'm not sure where to go from there as the error seems a bit vague.

Model.deploymentoptions

```
<DeploymentOptions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" 
xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" 
xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" 
xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" 
xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200">
  <PartitionDeployment>DeployPartitions</PartitionDeployment>
  <RoleDeployment>DeployRolesRetainMembers</RoleDeployment>
  <ProcessingOption>DoNotProcess</ProcessingOption>
  <ADALCache>None</ADALCache>
  <ConfigurationSettingsDeployment>Deploy</ConfigurationSettingsDeployment>
  <OptimizationSettingsDeployment>Deploy</OptimizationSettingsDeployment>
  <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
</DeploymentOptions>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that i was using SSMS 17.  I updated to ssms 18 and got a more informative error message.  So when deploy Analysis Services make sure you are using at least ssms 18.